# Git strange merge conflict on added file

Tags: json, git

I've experienced a strange merge conflict on git-managed .json file and have no clue how this happened.

Situation in summary : I added a data json file *A.json* in my branch A, and my colleague added a similar formatted data json file *B.json* in his branch B.

In normal scenario, when I merge branch B, B.json should be just added. Worked well until now - But, today git showed a merge conflict with my added A.json file.

We've already checked that branch A doesn't have file B.json, and branch B doesn't have file A.json.

Here's a screenshot of this conflict :

[image: (Conflict diff screenshot from sourcetree)]

I'm suspecting that git rename function may caused this, but not sure for that.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

*Edit

I've ran git diff on two commits(commit when A.json added and commit when B.json added) and confirmed git detected added files as renamed filed.

[image]

But still I'm not sure why git detected two different file addition as rename. Maybe I need to understand more on git's rename function...

Comment: I mean, there are clearly two versions of the same JSON file, each having a different value for the `"$id"` key.  You should check the history of the two branches involved in the merge to confirm this.  Just resolve the conflict and move on.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 'clearly two versions of the same JSON file' - No, It's clearly not two versions of the same json file, it's 'similarity index 65%' of different serialized json file which git misunderstood as renamed file. 'Check the history of the two branches', yes, and can confirm it's two different add commits on different two files. Git somehow detected this file addition as rename, I'll edit my question with more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git's merge mechanism relies on Git's *rename detection* mechanism.

A Git commit stores a snapshot of every file.  There is no extra information: there are just these files.  So:

- If someone adds some file *F* at some point, the diff from the old commit, which lacks file *F*, to the new commit, which has file *F*, includes the instruction: *add new file named F, with given content*.
- If someone *deletes* the file *F*, and makes a new commit, then the change from the old commit to the new one includes the instruction: *delete file named F*.
- **If someone *renames* the file *F1* to a new name *F2*, then the comparison between the old commit and the new one says *remove F1, and create new F2 with the given content.***

For the rename case, that's a valid way to get the right set of files: take the old commit, completely remove file *F1*, and create an all-new *F2* with the same content that *F1* had.  It's a *long* instruction, though, and humans tend to object to it: *I didn't **remove** the file, I **renamed** it!*  So `git diff` has the ability to check for this odd case: file *F1* has vanished and file *F2* has appeared in its place.  Maybe those are the same file after all.

---

Meanwhile, the `git merge` command means:

- Find some shared ancestor commit, from which both we and they (whoever "they" are) started.
- Compare the snapshot in the common ancestor to my current snapshot.  Whatever is changed, that's the work I / we did: the `ours` changes, it were.
- Compare the snapshot in the common ancestor to *their* snapshot, the one I told you about in the `git merge` command.  Whatever is changed, that's the work they did.

Now, suppose that in the common base commit, there's a file named `B.json`.  In your own commit, there's a file named `A.json` but *there is no `B.json` file*.  Did you *remove* `B.json` and add a completely new and different `A.json`?  Or, did you *rename* the existing `B.json` file to `A.json`, and maybe change it a bit?

Git does not, and cannot, know which event actually happened, but humans tend to prefer it when Git finds a rename, as long as the two files are "sufficiently similar".  How similar is *sufficiently similar?*  Git has a method for computing a *similarity index* between any two files.  The diff-or-merge can tell you what the similarity index was—to see it with `git diff` yourself, use `git diff --find-renames` to make sure you invoke the rename detector—and can compare it against some threshold.  The default threshold is 50%: files that are at least 50% similar are "the same file", even if the *name* changed.

The `-X no-renames` flag turns off the rename detection entirely.  The `-X find-renames=value` flag sets the minimum similarity index to the given percentage value (see the documentation for all the exact ways to write this percentage, but a two-digit number always works, so you can use `99` for 99%, `50` for the default 50%, and `03` for 3%; be aware that `3` means 30%).

As you have just seen, the rename detector *can* misfire, finding renames that never actually happened.  It can also fail to find a rename if not enough of the original file *content* was preserved.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!! It helped a lot understanding what's going on under the hood!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so a bit complicated scenario happened here.

First, I've found the root cause of this 'rename' thing with command

```
git merge --Xno-renames [branch_B]
```

The scenario :

1. My colleague added B.json and it's merged to other branch. I merged this other branch so B.json was added to my branch without notice.
2. During automated data cleanup in my branch, B.json was removed.
3. I added A.json. **Seems like git thought that B.json was renamed to A.json at this point.**
4. After then when I merge branch B, B.json creates conflict with A.json.

So rather than it's a bug or git rename problem, it seems more like our workflow flaw...

Answer (score 0):

I too think this is because of renaming the file. You can check this yourself:

```sh
git log -p -3 | grep -i 'renamed:'
```

...where `-3` limits the number of commits to list.

Git detects renaming based on the contents of the files.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it seems like rename is the reason of this conflict. After resolution git seems to not log conflicted files as rename, so I ran git diff and can confirm that git thinks two files are renamed.